# Error HTTP 413 Request entity too large (Entidad de solicitud demasiado larga) Bot Telegram

Tags: c#, api, telegram

Tengo un problema con el envío de notificaciones usando el Bot de Telegram, ya que me da

> error 413

Actualmente desarrollo un proyecto de .Net Framework en C# y a través de una `Trigger Function` realizo las notificaciones usando el Bot de Telegram, sin embargo el `Request` es muy largo y no sé cual es el máximo. ¿Dónde lo veo? ¿Cómo modificar ese máximo `Request`?

Comment: Hola. Puedes verificar en esa request el Content-Length de la misma?

Comment: Si, si puedo ver el `content-length`, pero no es el mismo que la cantidad de caracteres, o debería serlo? Porque utilicé `.length` para contar la cantidad de caracteres y lo comparé con el `content-length` y no son iguales. @SergioParraGuerra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude investigar al respecto y el máximo de caracteres por query es de 4096. Si se excede el límite, la query dará error.

En el siguiente link se puede ver más información al respecto https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage